# How to scroll a horizontal tile list by scrolling a HScrollBar?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a Tile list with list of user images, and also i have one HScrollBar component. Now if i scroll the Hscroll bar, `i want to also scroll the tile list`. And also i want the thumb of HScrollBar to adjust its width automatically depending on the number of elements in the data provider of the tile list. How can i do it?

This is how my code is

```
    <components:ExtendedTileList id="lstExpert" horizontalScrollBarStyleName="horizontalScroll" verticalScrollPolicy="off" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                                                         dataProvider="{expertsOnline}" height="80" width="100%" direction="vertical" maxRows="1"
                                                         itemRenderer="ExpertItemRenderer">
   </components:ExtendedTileList>
    <mx:HScrollBar id="customScrollExpert" styleName="horizontalScroll"  minScrollPosition="0"                                  lineScrollSize="20" pageScrollSize="20" y="68"
                                           scroll="hscrollbar1_scrollHandler(event)" visible="true" width="110%" height="5"/>
```

and my scroll event handler is

```
protected function hscrollbar1_scrollHandler(event:ScrollEvent):void
        {

            lstExpert.horizontalScrollPosition=event.target.scrollPosition ;

        }
```

Comment: Don't just write out your wishlist here.. Show us what you have tried, first.

Comment: @Loxxy,I have edited my question. Please take a look